# Object tag data attribute vs iframe src and form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First off, this is a (bad) workaround to have an external URL (i do not control) loaded into an `object` tag instead in a `iframe`, because there are issues with displaying media related to the content...but that's another story.

**I face the issue that my  'data' attribute won't update on .submit() but it does .on click()**

On a form submit (function) and among others, i request the external URL to load some search results.

With iframe the 'src' attribute gets updated on each submit 
`jQuery('#myDIV').attr('src','http://`... WORKS !

Using object tag, it won't update the data attribute value (after 1st request)
`jQuery('#myDIV').attr('data','http://...` WON'T WORK!

Trying to bind to a .on click() function however, then all works fine

What is it i am missing?
I remember to have read somewhere about data values being stored ... 
And looking at my console output, the URL query get's passed to the 'data' attribute just fine

Comment: can you provide a minimal example in a codepen | jsfiddle | .. - i cannot fully understand your structure - is it an object inside of an iframe? where is the submit? outside or inside the iframe?

Comment: i used iframe as an example, how it WOULD work with an iframe. My issue is with the object tag 'data' attribute

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a browser security feature may be involved. in my tests, updating the `data` did work when the new url was on the same domain (see below swapping a lowres google logo for a higher res one), but it did NOT work when the new resource was on a different domain.

However the examplke "d" shows a solution that also works with different domains, however it adds even more complexity to your workaround ;)

Different domain:

```js
url = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
button.onclick = e => {
  a.src = url;
  b.data = url;
  c.setAttribute("data", url);
  d.outerHTML = "<object data=" + url + " id=d width=200 height=200></object>";
}
```

```html
<iframe id=a width=200 height=200 src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/la6MoaRdqFiGag_v0pRTM15mb5wkaHlhEVIQiE7Lc9aGDNnLbN6tO-z1J-szI0mslcnw59NAr7n3wct5QOryOTG1SIQkpNYQO5_oFd0Fz8lHjMeTe1fO"></iframe>
<object id=b width=200 height=200 data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/la6MoaRdqFiGag_v0pRTM15mb5wkaHlhEVIQiE7Lc9aGDNnLbN6tO-z1J-szI0mslcnw59NAr7n3wct5QOryOTG1SIQkpNYQO5_oFd0Fz8lHjMeTe1fO"></object>
<object id=c width=200 height=200 data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/la6MoaRdqFiGag_v0pRTM15mb5wkaHlhEVIQiE7Lc9aGDNnLbN6tO-z1J-szI0mslcnw59NAr7n3wct5QOryOTG1SIQkpNYQO5_oFd0Fz8lHjMeTe1fO"></object>
<object id=d width=200 height=200 data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/la6MoaRdqFiGag_v0pRTM15mb5wkaHlhEVIQiE7Lc9aGDNnLbN6tO-z1J-szI0mslcnw59NAr7n3wct5QOryOTG1SIQkpNYQO5_oFd0Fz8lHjMeTe1fO"></object>
<a id=button>click me</a>
```

and this is on the same domain:

```js
url = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
button.onclick = e => {
  a.src = url;
  b.data = url;
  c.setAttribute("data", url);
  d.outerHTML = "<object data=" + url + " id=d width=200 height=200></object>";
}
```

```html
<iframe id=a width=200 height=200 src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"></iframe>
<object id=b width=200 height=200 data="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"></object>
<object id=c width=200 height=200 data="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"></object>
<object id=d width=200 height=200 data="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"></object>
<a id=button>click me</a>
```

Comment: that is not my issue. The 1st request is always successful, after that ..the url get's not updated in the data attribute, even the console output shows that the requested url is correct

Comment: have you tried the approach of "d" (replacing the outerhtml) instead of updating the data attr?

Comment: yes, before posting i tried that also. Actually, i am using jQuery 3x for that. So my approach was .replaceWith(). No luck either

Comment: i dont quite understand - it DOES work in my code - if it doesnt in yours, then something must be in your code preventing it from working. can you provide a minimal example in codepen or jsfiddle that doesnt work?